# How to do something before form submission without using preventing default

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony

my question is how can i do something before form submission witout doing `e.preventDefault();` ?

i have a situation where i got two form buttons and before form submission i want set hidden field value. I'm using symfony2 framework so when i submit form with post also is passed click button element so later in my backend i can know whit one was clicked.

`(1)` The problem is when i do something like this:

```
$('form[name="campaign"]').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    prepareInput();
    this.submit();
})
```

where `prepareInput()` gather data and set it to some hidden form field value.
with that solution later on i don't get the button value in request data `e.preventDefault()` brake it.

i tried to do something in case to don't use `e.preventDefault()` like i set empty callback in my `prepareInput()` method

```
function prepareInput(callback) {
    ...

    callback();
}
```

and changed my form submit method like this:

```
$('form[name="campaign"]').submit(function(e) {
    prepareInput(function() {
        return true;
    });
})
```

but still it doesn't w8 till my data is set in hidden field :( maybe is there some solution where i can add the button data to form post request after `e.preventDefault()` ?
I also should add that original here marked as `(1)` solution works using chrome, but doesn't at opera or firefox

@Update
i also tried to use buttons click events like this:

```
$(function()
{
    var $form = $('form[name="campaign"]');
    var $submitActors = $form.find('button[type=submit]');

    $submitActors.click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        prepareRecipients();
        $form.submit();
    });

});
```

@UPDATE2

```
function prepareInput(callback) {
    var hidden= $('#hidden');

    var valElements = $List.find('.list-group-item');
    var vals = [];

    valElements .each(function() {
        var val = $(this).data('info');
        vals .push(val);
    });
    hidden.val(JSON.stringify(vals));

    callback();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible in your code to hook click event on button and there you prepare the input and then submit the form manully?

Comment: i tried using `$('#button').click(function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    prepareInput();

    form.submit();
    });` but it simple also dosnt work at firefox or opera

Comment: `prepareInput` is async?

Comment: no it just take data from table and pare it to json then set the hidden field value, it all depends about the table size

Comment: Can you post the actual code of the `prepareInput` function? Knowing what it does is pretty important to answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.submit()` doesn't include the original submit button so i solved my problem by adding the button element to form after submit, here is the code:

```
$(function()
{
    var submitActor = null;
    var $form = $('form[name="campaign"]');
    var $submitActors = $form.find('button[type=submit]');

    $form.submit(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (null === submitActor)
        {
            submitActor = $submitActors[0];
        }

        prepareInput();

        var tempElement = $("<input type='hidden'/>");
        tempElement
                .attr("name", submitActor.name)
                .val($(submitActor).val())
                .appendTo($form);

        this.submit();

    });

    $submitActors.click(function(e)
    {
        submitActor = this;
    });

});
```

i hope it will help others int the future

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the submit button from your form and having a general `<button>` outside of your `<form>` tag?

This way when you click the button, you can process what you need and the form won't automatically submit.

Your call to process the form should still work after you have finished process the data how you want.

Answer (score 0):

In extenstion to comment above: What if you try this. prepareInput function is async, hence you don't know exactly when the field is set.

```
   $("#button").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            prepareInput(submitForm);

        });

function submitForm(){
 var $form=  $('form[name="campaign"]'); 
 $form.validate();
  if ($form.valid()) {
    $form.submit();
  }
}

    function prepareInput(callback)
    {

    //...when preparation is ready, check if value is set or wait sometime
     callback();
   /*
     if you need to wait (200ms.)
     setTimeout(function(){
       callback();
     },200);
   */

    }
```

Comment: The problem is jQuery.submit() doesn't include the original submit button when it is posted so I can't distinguish on the server button from button since they are both using the same form, and i need them to do so.